# How to fix an error of "objet de type 'closure' non indiçable" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a kNN test on a data set composed of numerical and catagorical data. 
I need to convert my catagorical data into numerical so I wrote the following code

```
summary(factor(data$gender))
data$gender <- as.numeric(data$gender == 'Male')
data$Partner <- as.numeric(data$Partner == 'No')
data$Dependents <- as.numeric(data$Dependents == 'No')
data$PhoneService <- as.numeric(data$PhoneService == 'No')
data$PaperlessBilling <- as.numeric(data$PaperlessBilling == 'No')
summary(data[c("gender","Partner","Dependents","PhoneService","PaperlessBilling")])
```

In the execution everything works just fine, however when I try to knit the code into HTML I get the following error

```
    Quitting from lines 32-39 (HW-kNN-MariamJallouli_Numercial_Categorical.Rmd) 
Error in data$gender : objet de type 'closure' non indiçable
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> summary -> factor
```

Comment: try not naming your data `data`. A `'closure'` is a function. And `data` is the name of a rather important function in the `utils` package.

Comment: This is very common error message in R. Indeed there was a talk with this title on the rstudio::conf. See https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2020/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable-jenny-bryan. As @Tom already mentioned. This error means that you are trying to subset a function. If I should guess you probably forgot to assign your dataset to the variable `data` in your Rmd. BTW: From this error message I learned that there is a function called `df` in R. That#s my shorthand for naming dataframes.